# style lint quick fix in vs code not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, stylelint

Is there a way to use style lint quick fix in VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

with [My Code Actions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.my-code-actions) you can write Quick Fixes yourself for the most frequent errors you make based on the diagnostics in the PROBLEMS panel.